# Area of Shaded Region Concentric Circles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

I have been asked to show that the shaded area of to concentric circles, one of radii $B$ (the smaller one) and the other of radii $A+B$ (the larger) is $\pi(A-B)(A+B)$.

What I have tried

$\pi R^{2}-\pi r^{2}=a$ (this is the area of the shaded area)

$\pi(A+B)^{2}-\pi B^{2}=a$

$\pi[(A+B)^{2}-B^{2}]=a$

$\pi(A^{2}+2AB+B^{2}-B^{2})=a$

$\pi(A^{2}+2AB)=a$

$\pi(A(A+2B))=a$

But I dont get how to reach the proposed expression.

**UPDATE**
The radii is wrong the correct is not $A+B$, instead it is radii $A$ the larger one and $B$ the small.

Comment: Are you sure the radii are A+B and B, not A and B?

Comment: Let me check ...

Comment: Thats right I didnt read the figure right, the radiis are A and B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good attempt, it seems that you just misread the radii.

\begin{align}
\pi (A^2-B^2) = \pi(A-B)(A+B)
\end{align}

p/s: If you want to compute the difference of two squares and then factorize it, using the formula $(A^2-B^2)= (A+B)(A-B)$ is faster.

In your working, $(A+B)^2-B^2=(A+2B)A$ can be achieved in a single step.